# Android/Java: Split Data in an Array and display

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do something extremely basic! And it wont work :(. I feel like I'm going in circles.

Here's the rundown: I would like the user to input a series of numbers into an EditText box (separated by comma's). After the add button is selected a split method will separate each number into its own slot in a String[]. EVENTUALLY, if I can get this part to work, the numbers will be pulled out of the array and converted to doubles.Then they will be used in a calculation or two. I have tried several different ways of getting this done and it seems like the problem is coming from the split method or for-loop. The code listed below returns an empty string.

Also, through my trial and error I ended up with a return method calculate(). How much stuff can a cram in an onClick method? Was this a bad idea? Please be as a brutal as needed!!! I'm new to android. Thanks in advance.

---

```
package com.simplydesign.android.standarddev;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    final EditText userData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final TextView dataCollection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] rawData;
            rawData = userData.getText().toString().split(",");
            dataCollection.setText(calculate(rawData));
        }

    });

}

public String calculate(String[] a) {

    String output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        output += " " + a[i];
        } return output;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for-loop you should iterate from 0 to `a.length - 1`. This means the loop must look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

But you'd better use something like that:

```
public String calculate(String[] a) {

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (String s : a) {
        output.append(' ').append(s);
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't think it will completly solve your problem but it definitely fixes one error.

Comment: That seemed to work! That's the first time I have used StringBuilder. Its not listed anywhere in my Java textbook from last semester. hm, imagine that. Thanks everyone, for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using getEditableText() instead of geText().

Comment: -1 This makes no difference unless the EditText widget has un-editable text in which case it would be returning null. An NPE is not what his problem is so I assume this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
```

... should be ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

I am guessing in all your tests, you were just using 2 number separated by commas, I spotted the problem as soon as I entered 3 numbers into your code.